# Develop Alarm Application

Tags: android, alarmmanager, commonsware, wakelock

I'd like develop an Alarm Application.
The application should work like this:

- launch it
- the activity show me the time
- I can set the alarm
- I can close the application
- when the alarm time comes , it starts an activity (even if the device is locked)

I have tried to adapt this sample https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful but I cannot launch an activity when the  alarm time comes.

I use this code to setup the alarm (for test I have inserted this code on an `onCreate` method of activity):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnAlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
            pendingIntent);
```

this is the OnAlarmReceiver class:

```
public class OnAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(ClockActivity.LOG_TAG, "OnAlarmReceiver::onReceive");
        WakefulIntentService.sendWakefulWork(context, AlarmService.class);
    }
}
```

this is the service class:

```
public class AlarmService extends WakefulIntentService {

    public AlarmService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doWakefulWork(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(ClockActivity.LOG_TAG, "AlarmService::doWakefulWork");
        Intent newIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ClockActivity.class);
        newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        newIntent.setAction(ClockActivity.ALARM_ACTION);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(newIntent);
    }
}
```

this is the portion of Manifest where are setup the service and the receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".OnAlarmReceiver"></receiver>
<service android:name=".AlarmService"></service>
```

the doWakefulWork method is never called!

Comment: Post your code, preferably where you try to launch your activity, and also report any errors that your getting...that'll help us help you.

Comment: does it work when the screen is on? I'm just trying to find out if the issue relates to the wake lock

Comment: as @PayPal_Tim asked in an "answer" (instead of adding a comment here) does `Log.i(ClockActivity.LOG_TAG, "OnAlarmReceiver::onReceive");` run ?

Answer (score 3):

I have made this application:

**AlarmActivity.java**

```
package com.foo;
import pack.breceiver.MyBroadcastReceiver;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public void startAlert(View view) {
        EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time);
        int i = Integer.parseInt(text.getText().toString());
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis()
                + (i * 1000), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set in " + i + " seconds",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
package pack.breceiver;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver  {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Don't panik but your time is up!!!!",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*// Vibrate the mobile phone
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);  */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out : http://blog.nelsondev.net/?p=124

using"alarmmanager"

```
 alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
    AlarmCal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES,
    pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I resolved removing the receiver from manifest and set in my code registering him with registerReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an instantiation exception maybe ?

You should have a public no arg constructor in your service :

```
public class AlarmService extends WakefulIntentService {

    public AlarmService() {
        super("AlarmService");
    }
    // etc
}
```