# Reducing power consumption

Tags: java, android, wakelock

For my application, I want to have a `Notification` sent to the user at a specified time. To do this, I have set up a `Timer` and the corresponding `TimerTask`.
To be sure the `Notification` will be sent to the user even if the phone is aslept, I have acquired a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK`. The problem is that this method draws a lot of power from my battery (my application is responsible for more than 50% of all the power consumption at the end of the day).

Is there another way (a more power efficient one of course) to do what I want to do?

Thanks in advance for the time you will spend trying to help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482045/develop-alarm-application might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  > Is there another way (a more power efficient one of course) to 
  > [have a Notification sent to the user at a specified time]?
```

You can use an the android AlarmManager for this.

See [Using AlarmManager to Schedule Activities on Android](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) as a tutorial and example.