# Running Certain Task based on time in android

Tags: android, service, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

Requirement here is to  trigger some task (like enabling\disabling wifi ) on particular time(suppose 8am) of a particular day(suppose Wednesday an Tuesday) in a week
Application may or may not be in foreground.There will be multiple schedules.

1.After searching on  Google I came across approach of using **alarm manger** and **register a event** using **BroadcastReceiver**  for particular time and day I want and **call service** to execute the task and terminate service when task is done.
(I doubt how next day timing events can be register and keep repeating those events on weekly basis)

2.Create **all time running service** and then use **alarm manager** to create **broadcast receiver for  just today's event** and  **call thread** to execute the task and terminate thread when task is done. (service will read database for everyday's schedule and define appropriate broadcast listener for a day)

Which approach correct ? better alternatives ?

Comment: Already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4482045/develop-alarm-application

Comment: External source: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/05/create-alarm-set-on-specified-time.html